# Server Error in '/' Application while running asp.net tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net, dreamweaver

Hi guys im testing out an asp.net script as im a newbie and am still learning. I'm running this on dreamweaver. Whenever i run the page. I get this error.

I'm actually trying to replicate this http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/util/srcview.aspx?path=~/aspnet/samples/data/GridViewBoundFields.src
with my own sql table and database.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>GridView Bound Fields</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Course" DataField="Course" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
SelectCommand="SELECT Course FROM tmdsi"
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: test%>" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my web config file is

```
<configuration>  
<connectionStrings>  
<add name="test"   
connectionString="Server=myipaddress; port=3306;Integrated Security=True;
Database=test;User=test; Password=test;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  
</connectionStrings>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why not you are using Visual studio express edition?

Comment: change the CutomError mode to ON to see what is the exact error in web.config

Comment: Visual Studio is a far better experience, try it.

Comment: actually guys, i do not know how to create a website using VB, but i will give it a try! :)
@sajanyamaha, it throws me out the same error even after changing it in IIS and stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give port separated by comma, read more about connection strings **[here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)**

Change

```
Server=myipaddress; port=3306;
```

To

```
Server=myipaddress,3306;
```

*Also change the CutomError mode to OFF to see what error exactly you are getting.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and help. After changing the port, its the same error. i tried to set to "On" the pages still remains the same. I tried to enter IIS to set to detailed error msg still the same.

Comment: Build website to make sure you getting the changes, if build is successfuly try accessing the page again. Also try debugging the code.

Comment: Hi Adil, i am not using VB. I am using Dreamweaver.

Comment: How you compile then? It better to download visual studio express version, http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads

Comment: I don't compile? I save the config files and run in on my web server.

Comment: You better download visual studio express, it will make your work lot more easier.

Comment: Alright. i'll do that. Just a question, since im a newbie at vs. How do i get them to run on my web server?